# How to get the first row that appears first in the data?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data set shown as below:

```
data <- tribble(
  ~shop_name, ~products, ~category_name,
  "A",         1,          "Game",
  "A",         1,          "Book",         
  "A",         2,          "Electronic",
  "A",         3,          "Home", 
  "B",         5,          "Game",
  "B",         5,          "Electronic",
  "B",         8,          "Home",
  "C",         1,          "Book",
  "C",         7,          "Game",
  "C",         9,          "Game",
)
```

I wanted to see the top 1 category based on the products, and coded this:

```
data %>% 
  group_by(shop_name) %>% 
  top_n(1, products) %>% 
  mutate(top_category = toString(category_name))
```

But because products have sometimes same values per each shop_name, there are more than one category names in the "top_category". How can I get the first row that appears first in the dataset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `dplyr::first`:

```
data %>% 
  group_by(shop_name) %>% 
  summarise(products = first(products),
            category_name = first(category_name))
```

To keep all columns without explicitly specifying them

```
data %>% 
  group_by(shop_name) %>% 
  summarise_all(first)
```

**Output**

```
# shop_name products category_name
#  <chr>        <dbl> <chr>        
# 1 A                1 Game         
# 2 B                5 Game         
# 3 C                1 Book
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But I have more columns than the data I've shared. Is there any way to keep other columns as well?

Comment: Well, do you mean that I should code like this?

data %>% 
  group_by(shop_name) %>%
  summarise(products = first(products),
            category_name = first(category_name)) %>%
  summarise_all(first)

Comment: Use the second code chunk: `data %>% 
  group_by(shop_name) %>% 
  summarise_all(first)`

Answer (score 1):

```
data %>% 
  group_by(shop_name) %>% 
  top_n(1, desc(products)) %>%
  plyr::ddply( "shop_name", head, 1)
```

```
  shop_name products category_name
1         A        1          Game
2         B        5          Game
3         C        1          Book
```